# How can I look up classes of ImageNet?

Tags: dataset, image-classification

After downloading the imagenet urls ([link](http://image-net.org/download-imageurls)), I see that it is a single 1.1 GB text file which starts like this:

```
n00004475_6590    http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3175/2737866473_7958dc8760.jpg
n00004475_15899    http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3276/2875184020_9944005d0d.jpg
n00004475_32312    http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4094333885_e8462a8338.jpg
n00004475_35466    http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3289/2809605169_8efe2b8f27.jpg
n00004475_39382    http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_SrRTF97Kbfo/SUqT9y-qTVI/AAAAAAAABmg/saRXhruwS6M/s400/bARADEI.jpg
n00004475_41022    http://fortunaweb.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Caroline-Atkinson-FMI.jpg
n00004475_42770    http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3488/4051378654_238ca94313.jpg
n00004475_54295    http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3368/3198142470_6eb0be5f32.jpg
n00005787_13    http://www.powercai.net/Photo/UploadPhotos/200503/20050307172201492.jpg
n00005787_32    http://www.web07.cn/uploads/Photo/c101122/12Z3Y54RZ-22027.jpg
```

I'm pretty sure `n00004475_6590` is the class of the image. How can I look up what this means (in natural language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part before the underscore can be entered in this URL:

http://www.image-net.org/api/text/wordnet.synset.getwords?wnid=n00004475

Comment: what is the second part, after undescore?

Comment: Seems this API no longer works (I got a 404).